# Angular 7 sending two requests at once, one with data other one without

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build an hybrid mobile application using ionic 4 and angular 7 unfortunately getting some errors because when i make an http post request it's executing two times where the first request is without data but the other one has it. I think that some of my fellows are right saying that the problem is not coming from angular but according to what i learnt today the problem is that once a request is sent it tries to check its safety using an OPTIONS request before sending the request we expect to send now can someone help me to avoid that preflight request

```
  logIn(user){

    return this.http.post<Users>(base_url + 'login.json',{
      email: user.username, 
      password: user.password
    })
    .subscribe(data =>{

      this.store.set('__authToken', data.__authToken).then(data => {
        // AUTH_TOKEN = token;
        resolve(data)
      },
      error => {
        reject(error);
      });
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    // AUTH_TOKEN = 'Bearer 12345';
    // localStorage.setItem('_authToken', AUTH_TOKEN);
    // this.authenticationState.next(true);
  }
```

Comment: may be the first is OPTIONS 204 no?

Comment: can you share your component code as well where you are calling this function

Comment: I am having the same problem, and the Q&As that I can find are similar to here, they do not provide a conclusive answer of what is happening. Obs.: it makes me said that people downvote what they cannot answer here, I think creates a bad environment for learning.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know for sure if this is what is causing your problem because I can't see the component code that is calling this, but it is likely you are subscribing twice. The http request is sent when the observable, in this case http.post, is subscribed to. So subscribing to login and also subscribing to the post could be causing duplicate requests

I would change your login to look something like this:

```
login() {
    return this.http.post<Users>(base_url + 'login.json',{
      email: user.username, 
      password: user.password
    }).pipe(
        catchError(() => {}) // do something if error
    )
}
```

Then wherever you are calling it do something like this

```
login().subscribe(data => {
    this.store.set('__authToken', data.__authToken).then(data => {
        // AUTH_TOKEN = token;
        resolve(data)
      },
      error => {
        reject(error);
      });
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
})
```

Alternatively if you want the store logic to be inside of the login method you could utilize [Map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) and do something like this:

```
login() {
        return this.http.post<Users>(base_url + 'login.json',{
          email: user.username, 
          password: user.password
        }).pipe(
            map(data => {
              this.store.set('__authToken', data.__authToken).then(data => {
                 // AUTH_TOKEN = token;
                 resolve(data)
              },
              error => {
                 reject(error);
              });
            })
            catchError(() => {}) // do something if error
        )
}
```

And when your calling it do something like this:

```
login().subscribe(res => { console.log(res) }, error => { console.log(error) })
```

[Here is a nice short video to watch about a lot of the operators you can use with rxjs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewcoEYS85Co&t=524s)

Comment: Thanks so much friend but it seems that you didn't understand very well what my question was. My problem is that it's making two requests yet i subscribed to the observable once and moreover the first request does not have the datas that i post but the second one has which makes my api to only consider the first request without any post values (in php $_POST is being an empty array for the first request which is considered)

Comment: @WinnersProx can you edit your answer to include what is calling the login() function so I can try to duplicate the problem on my end

Comment: @WinnersProx also what is the status request of the first request that is sent

Comment: The status that is being sent back is 200